# Как удалить элемент в массиве?

Tags: javascript

```
Array.prototype.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])
```

MDN спецификация:

> изменяет содержимое массива, удаляя элементы и/или добавляя новые.
>   Возвращает массив удалённых элементов.

```
m.splice(2, 1);
[3]       // m равно [1, 2, 4, 5]

m.splice(1, 2);
[2, 4]    // m равно [1, 5]
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, как удалить элемент в массиве?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит обратиться к [данной документации](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Метод splice – это универсальный раскладной нож для работы с массивами. Умеет все: удалять элементы, вставлять элементы, заменять элементы – по очереди и одновременно.

пример удаления элемента:

```
var arr = ["Я", "изучаю", "JavaScript"];
arr.splice(1, 1); // начиная с позиции 1, удалить 1 элемент
alert( arr ); //  осталось ["Я", "JavaScript"]
```

удаление трех первых элементов и добавление на их место двух:

```
var arr = ["Я", "сейчас", "изучаю", "JavaScript"];
// удалить 3 первых элемента и добавить другие вместо них
arr.splice(0, 3, "Мы", "изучаем")
alert( arr ) // теперь ["Мы", "изучаем", "JavaScript"]
```

сам метод splice возвращает удаленные элементы:

```
var arr = ["Я", "сейчас", "изучаю", "JavaScript"];
// удалить 2 первых элемента
var removed = arr.splice(0, 2);
alert( removed ); // "Я", "сейчас" <-- удаленные элементы
```

splice также может вставлять элементы без удаления, для этого достаточно установить deleteCount в 0:

```
var arr = ["Я", "изучаю", "JavaScript"];
// с позиции 2
// удалить 0
// вставить "сложный", "язык"
arr.splice(2, 0, "сложный", "язык");
alert( arr ); // "Я", "изучаю", "сложный", "язык", "JavaScript"
```